# Session_regenerate_id error in MacOS

Tags: yii

I have the following code in yii

```
$identity=new UserIdentity($username,$password);
if($identity->authenticate())
{
    Yii::app()->User->login($identity);
    $this->redirect(array('site/index'));
}
else
{

}
```

It works fine on XAMPP in Windows environment. But when i test it in Mac OS it gives the following error

> session_regenerate_id(): Cannot regenerate session id - headers
>   already sent

Can anyone explain why this is happening and fix the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php/8028987#8028987

Comment: Already 2 duplicates, one with answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756021/session-regenerate-id-headers-already-sent-in-unit-testing-yii-controller http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580140/yii-error-session-regenerate-id However this problem occurs when using "Remember me" feature and session expired, and there is no real answer, only workarounds.